# JDBC driver not found even though added through Maven

Tags: java, maven, jdbc

I have my JDBC driver added through maven. My application works fine when i run it locally so i know the syntax is correct/server is set up correctly but whenever i try to run on the server it fails...

```
Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://host:3306/DBName", "username", "password");
```

I believe i have maven setup correctly as my other dependancies are fine. I've also tried and mvn clean install and that work, i could see the JDBC driver in my .m2 folder. Any suggestions?

Comment: Add more information, post your maven, the code that is instantiating the connection and the error that you get. Otherwise this is impossible to solve.

Comment: What is the failure?  (A stack trace would be very helpful here.)

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found

Comment: did you write `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` line?

Comment: If it works fine when running locally, but not elsewhere(?), that means the JDBC driver jar file is not available "elsewhere". Did you package it up correctly?

Comment: @mustafacil `Class.forName` hasn't been needed for many Java versions (since Java 6).

Comment: @Andreas I added it to my maven build. Isn't that all that's needed? My other maven dependancies work fine

Comment: Why don't you just **check** if the JDBC jar file is packaged correctly, rather than assume "added it to my maven build" did it? It's called *research*, and you should learn how to do that.

Comment: I only came here because i didn't find an answer to my problem... i don't see any errors when i run maven and i see the jar in the .m2 repository. I also haven't changed anything and my other dependencies were packaged correctly. Is there another way to check that it's been packaged correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ever installed manually the JDBC driver (https://cdivilly.wordpress.com/2009/07/16/add-oracle-jdbc-jar-to-maven-repository/)? And after that made that the external jar installed were recognized for the Maven?